# JQuery SetTimeout before running code

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to run a function in JQuery that basically shuts down or starts up a server. The code I have so far is this -

```
$(".stopServer").click(function(){
    $.post("controller.php",{stop: 'true', server: this.name});
    $('#test'+this.name).load('controller.php?status=true&server='+this.name);
});
```

The problem is obviously it stops the server fine but it updates the status div ('#test'+this.name) straight away. This is no good because the server takes a period of time to shut down. I've been trying to get SetTimeout to work but can't figure it out... Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks guys, you're the best :)

UPDATE:

Full functions are here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".startServer").click(function(){
    $.post("controller.php",{server: this.name});
    setTimeout("showStatus('"+this.name+"')", 3000);
});

$(".stopServer").click(function(){
    $.post("controller.php",{stop: 'true', server: this.name});
    setTimeout("showStatus('"+this.name+"')", 3000);
});

function showStatus(name) {
    alert(name);
    $('#test'+name).load('controller.php?status=true&server='+name);
}
});
```

UPDATE

Given up on the idea of it, instead the status is polled for every second instead.

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
    $('.status').each(function() {
    var $name = $(this).attr('name');
    $(this).load("controller.php?status=true&server=" + $name);

});
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added a quick sample of wrapping the function in a `setTimeout`

```
​$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(){
        var message = 'hello';
        setTimeout(function(){ callback(message) },1000); 
    });
    function callback(name){
        alert(name);
    }        
});​
```

[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GQvt9/)

Comment: I've given up, I just poll for the status every second instead.

Comment: @Steve - cool; well here is demo if you decide to change your mind! goodluck!

Comment: Does what I wanted anyways, so I'll give you the chosen answer :) Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if you will get a response from 'controller.php' when the server actually shuts down, in case you don't, try this...

```
$(".stopServer").click(function(){
    $.post("controller.php",{stop: 'true', server: this.name});
    setTimeout("showStatus('"+this.name+"')", 10000);
});

function showStatus(name) {
    $command = $('#test'+name).load('controller.php?status=true&server='+name);
}
```

Comment: @Steve, this is probably your best bet for what you're trying to do. The `10000` means 10 seconds delay and he is passing a function as a parameter.

Comment: This is definetly what I'm trying to achieve, but it isn't working... It's running the shutdown command, but not updating the div.

Comment: Try debugging it to see what is going on, if you are using chrome or firefox use the developer tools and use breakpoints to see what is actually happening :)

Comment: Yeah I'm trying, I can get it to run like this - setTimeout(showStatus(this.name), 5000); - but the delay doesn't work.

Comment: @Steve that will run it instantly; you might need to wrap the above answer in this: `setTimeout(function(){ showStatus(this.name)}, 10000);`

Comment: Ok, just update your question at the top with the full piece including hte showStatus function.

Answer (score 1):

ajax calls are asynchronous. the $.post() call returns immediately and lets the actual post work be done in the background. either change it to a synchronous call (usually not a good idea), or put the subsequent code in the "success" part of the .post call, e.g.

```
$.post('controller.php', success: function(data) {
    $command = etc....
});
```

Comment: Don't think the server would've shutdown by the time the post completes; guess thats why he's asking for a setTimeout or interval solution.

Comment: Yeah the server takes 3 seconds to shut down, the command to tell it to do that returns after like, milliseconds...

Comment: at least the JS stuff will wait for the server-side script to return, instead of just zooming on to the next line of code. I'd put the delay into the success handler as well, so the 3 second count starts AFTER you've gotten confirmation the shutdown command was issued.

Comment: I don't know how to do the delay. I'm not concerned about it zooming into the next line of code, it literally just sends the word "stop" to a console.